# Asp .net core app authorization against Azure AD groups

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have a .net core 2.0 service in which I'm trying to implement authorization by reading groups from AAD

What was done:

1. in the Azure portal, in the app registration, modified the manifest - added "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
2. In the app registration -> API permissions -> Gave permission

[Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2ZiI.png)

In the code:

```
   public static class AuthorizationPolicy
    {
        public static string Name => "GroupName";

        public static void Build(AuthorizationPolicyBuilder builder) =>
            builder.RequireClaim("GroupName", "06edc7ed-b0da-425f-b4a3-f501904e6c6f");
    }
```

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
options.AddPolicy("GroupName", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new IsMemberOfGroupRequirement("GroupName", "06edc7ed-b0da-425f-b4a3-f501904e6c6f")));
});

Added AuthorizationHandler class

```
public class IsMemberOfGroupHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IsMemberOfGroupRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IsMemberOfGroupRequirement requirement)
    {
        var groupClaim = context.User.Claims
            .FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "groups" &&
                                     claim.Value.Equals(requirement.GroupId, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (groupClaim != null)
            context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

But the groups don't exist in the user's Claims

Please assist, what I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

It seems your registered app is used to request graph api. So the `groups` claim doesn't exist in access token.

Here is what we need to know about `groups` claim:

If we register a app in AD as clientApp and register another app(for web app or api app) in AD as backendApp. And then add the permissions of backendApp into clientApp, request access token according to clientApp. Now, the access token will contain `groups` claim if you add `"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"` in manifest of backendApp. **We can limit the user can/can't do any operation of backendApp according to his group (because the backendApp(webapp or api app) is belong to us**.

But if you register app in AD as clientApp to request token for graph api, graph api backendApp is not belong to us and it just exists an enterprise app for graph api in AD. So we can't modify its manifest. So the access token doesn't contain `groups` claim. Actually, as graph api is not belong to use, **so it is meaningless to limit the user can/can't do any operation according to his group**.

So the problem is by design. If you still want to get `groups` cliam, you can get it in "id_token". Add a `openid` in "scope", then the response will contain "id_token". Decode the "id_token" in [this](https://jwt.io/) page, you can find `groups` claim.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean to register an app as a client or backend, what is the difference?
and where can I choose in which mode to register the app?

Comment: Hi @StasMashkovich The registered app which you mentioned in `What was done:` in your description is as client app and graph is as backend app(in your situation you do not need to register the backend app in AD). As I mentioned in my answer, the access token doesn't contain `groups` claim in your situation, it is by design.

Comment: @StasMashkovich If my answer helps your question, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~